# DotnetOpenAuth - POST message to the service which accepts different charset

Tags: .net, character-encoding, dotnetopenauth

I am developing the remote blog editor which uses openAPI services.
But, when I send POST request with parameters in Korean, the characters of the registered post are broken. GET request works fine.

I use DotnetOpenAuth.
How can I solve this problem while using DotnetOpenAuth?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to set the encoding type in your HTTP headers.  That's orthogonal to DotNetOpenAuth so just set the header on your `HttpWebRequest`.